# How to run a python script between a particular times every single day (on Linux)?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, cron

I am looking for a way to be able to run a python script at a particular times of day and then have it auto terminated at another time of day. Ideally, I would want this to not be done within the script itself.

For example: I would want the script to start at 08:00 and end at 10:00 then start again at 11:30 and then terminate at 15:00 and I would need this to happen every day automatically.

I have browsed through many suggestions online, and many of them suggested to use `cron`, however, as far as I can see, `cron` does not natively offer the functionality of automatically terminating an application.

Others have [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445088/cron-job-start-and-stop-at-certain-time) using cron to start the application at a particular time and then use another cron instance to create a "terminate" file that the program will search for at every loop iteration and if the file is present then the python script will terminate via a sys.exit() function or something, however, this seems quite janky and more of a workaround than a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Jobber. You will be able to start scripts whenever you want and for the time you want.
Warning : Jobber is not free. You can try it for free though.
[Here](https://getjobber.com/) is the link to Jobber's website.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script that creates a lockfile with `cron`  (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12815/what-are-pid-and-lock-files-for), and use the lockfile to know what the process ID is, then terminate the process with that id using `cron` as well

Answer (score 0):

After you have determined that the process name is uniquely identifiable you could do something like this (that's indeed also using `cron`).

```
 0  8 * * * /path/to/unique_name.py& ( echo "pkill unique_name.py" | at 10:00 )
30 11 * * * /path/to/unique_name.py& ( echo "pkill unique_name.py" | at 15:30 )
```

Edit 1:

And "name safe" versions (using `kill`).

```
 0  8 * * * /path/to/unique_name.py& echo kill $! | at 10:00
30 11 * * * /path/to/unique_name.py& echo kill $! | at 15:30
```

Comment: What do you mean by ```determined that the process name is uniquely identifiable```? Does it just mean that the python script name is unique?

Comment: I'm using `pkill`, which kills processes by name. If you e.g. killed everything `python` that might not be what you want. @user13834264

Comment: My script spawns multiple threads and so will show up as multiple processes to the OS. I would imagine I would need to find a way of finding the process ID of the main thread?

Comment: @user13834264 That pid is indeed the one of the parent process. If killing that makes all the children go away, you're sweet.